# timing single function in a hybrid code of MPI/OpenMP

Tags: mpi, openmp

I have a hybrid code with MPI/OpenMP. I want to know what is the time spent for particular function, let's say A, for every MPI process. This function is called inside the OpenMP do/for loops also in a very complicated way by various functions on top of it (i.e. some other functions let's say B and C may be calling A which also might be inside the OpenMP do/for loops). I was planning to do it as follows:

```
double A()
{
 time1 = MPI_Wtime();
 //compute result...
 //Note: inside this function there is no OpenMP or MPI calls...
 //      just pure computation of results...
 time2 = MPI_Wtime();
 printf("myRank=%d timeSpent=%f\n", myRank, (time2-time1));
 return result;
}
```

Would the sum of all the times per every MPI process be the total time spent for this function by that MPI process? If not please can you show me how to get it correctly, thanks!

Comment: the way you are doing it every Thread/MPI process would have its own time1 and time2

Comment: @pyCthon can you suggest a way to get only per MPI process? thanks!!!

Comment: @torem, VampirTrace in fully instrumented mode (the default one) would trace the execution of every single function of your code (or you could write a filter to limit it to `A()` only) across all processes in the MPI job and then Vampir (commercial) or Scalasca (open-source) can be used to analyse the OTF traces.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks, but in the machine I am using I do not have VampirTrace... :(

Comment: Scalasca is open-source and you can build it yourself (one does not need administrator privileges to do so). VampirTrace is also open-source. As for Vampir, I think you could obtain an evaluation license. If you use Intel MPI there is a chance that Intel's Trace Analyzer and Collector comes as part of the package. It has almost the same tracing and analysis abilities as VampirTrace+Vampir as they both descend from the same parent project.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to trace only a single function with VampirTrace? Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, it is. Consult the VT manual on how to write filters.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks! I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't want to reinvent the wheel and we don't want to reinvent the MPI profiler. That would be hard.

There are very powerful tools available from the manufactures of many cluster systems. For example Cray machines usually come with CrayPat which [spits out magic](http://www.nersc.gov/users/software/debugging-and-profiling/craypat/).

Additionally there is free software such as this http://mpip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I used crayPat. Got only one result for my function A, i.e. not per MPI process I am running, it says in table that "User time (approx) 100.055 sec", for which MPI process is this?

Comment: @torem You are tying to address load imbalance? I think the link I mentioned gives exact instructions on how to do this. You should post your compile lines and maybe open a CrayPat specific question on SO. Perhaps you should modify your post with the patreport command you issued. Because CrayPat is made to show exactly this information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to reinvent the wheel but to use some professional grade software already built for profiling such as [TAU](https://nesccdocs.rdhpcs.noaa.gov/wiki/index.php/Profiling_Codes), or [MPIP](http://mpip.sourceforge.net) or [Gprof](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/performance_tools/exercise.html#6.%20gprof) ...

heres a decent [presentation](http://www.chpc.utah.edu/docs/presentations/vampir/TAU06.pdf) to get you started

Comment: I tried using gprof, but it did not create gmon files per MPI process, it only did create single gmon.out. Then I did "gprof a.exe gmon.out" it gave me nothing...

Comment: you need to add environment variables, also(if your on linux) you don't need the .exe for your object files its in the third link if you scroll down